# Node async explanation needed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am having trouble understanding what's going wrong with the code below. I have a function called `importOrder` which imports an order by converting a given object into a new order object. What I would like to do is, for each product (`line_item`) in the given object, fetch the product details and add to the new order object (`newOrder.products`). The problem is that the array is always empty. I know this is a common question, but I just don't understand what is going on (is it a closure thing?)

Here is the bespoke code

```js
'use strict';

var Promise = require('promise');
var Order = require('./models/order');
var shopifyAPI = require('shopify-node-api');
var config = require('config');

var orderImporter = {

  importOrderFromShopify: function (shopifyOrder) {

    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
      var newOrder = new Order({
        external_id: shopifyOrder.name,
        status: 'Awaiting Fulfillment',
        date_created: shopifyOrder.created_at,
        subtotal_inc_tax: shopifyOrder.subtotal_price,
        tracking_number: "",
        order_source: "www",
        payment_method: "Credit Card",
        invoice_printed_at: null,
        packing_slip_printed_at: null,
        products: [],  // this is the array I would like to populate with product details fetched from shopify
        product_options: []
      });

      shopifyOrder.line_items.forEach(function(lineItem){
        var productId = lineItem.product_id;
        var product = {};
        (function(newOrder){
          loadProductImage(productId)
            .then(function(imageUrl){
              product.image = imageUrl;
              newOrder.products.push(product);
            }, function(error){
              console.log(error);
            });
        })(newOrder);
        });

      newOrder.save(function(error){
        if (error){
          reject(error);
        } else {
          fulfill(newOrder);
        }
      });

    });


    function loadProductImage(productId){

      return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
        var shopifyClient = new shopifyAPI({
          shop: config.get('shopify_config.shop'),
          shopify_api_key: 'xxxx',
          shopify_shared_secret: 'yyyyy',
          access_token: 'zzzzzzzz',
          verbose: false
        });

        shopifyClient.get('/admin/products/' + productId + '/images.json', function(error, data){

          if(error){
            reject(error);
          } else {
            fulfill(data.images[0].src);
          }
        });
      });

    }

  }
};

module.exports = orderImporter;
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank You for formatting my post - I am sure your modifications have made it much clearer and easier for others to read!

Comment: No problem, but note that you still need to add a [mcve], showing inputs and expected and actual outputs, not just this snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.map` instead of `.forEach` and return array of promises. Then wait until all promises resolved with `Promise.all`. And then you can save new order and fulfill your `importOrderFromShopify` promise

Comment: Hi @user1280859 thank you for your response. I'm not sure what you mean by 'return array of promises'. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Ben `var productDetealsPromises = shopifyOrder.line_items.map(function(e){ /* some aditional stuff*/ return loadProductImage(productId)  }); Promise.all(productDetealsPromises).then(/* now all promises fulfilled, you can handle and save result*/)`

Comment: Thank you very much! This has helped me a lot!